# Swift 5 - documentPicker not called after a file was selected

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm working on a Swift 5 project and I need to implement a document picker for which users can select a music file to be processed. The document picker is shown in the interface, but the documentPicker function is not being called after a document was selected in the UI.

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Button("Select files to sync") {
                ImportMenuController().selectFile()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**ImportMenuController.swift** called by ContentView.swift:

```
//  ImportMenuController.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

class ImportMenuController: UIViewController {
    
    func selectFile() {
        let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [UTType.mp3], asCopy: true)
        importMenu.delegate = self
        importMenu.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        importMenu.shouldShowFileExtensions = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

        while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
            topMostViewController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topMostViewController
    }
}

extension ImportMenuController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

   func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){
        print("documentPicker opened")
    }

   func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
       print("documentPickerWasCancelled opened")
    }

}
```

I experimented with different ways of calling the documentPicker, but unfortunately, I still didn't manage to arrive in the documentPicker or the documentPickerWasCancelled function, so the `print` commands are never executed. Ultimately, I need to retrieve the fileUrl for the selected file to process it further. What am I doing wrong?

**Reference**

[Current Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerdelegate/2902364-documentpicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retain the `document-picker` delegate (in this case, the instance of ImportMenuController).

This fixes it for you.

```
let importer = ImportMenuController()
var body: some View {
   ZStack() {
       Button("Select files to sync") {
           importer.selectFile()
       }
   }
```